# How can i make a 4 legs spider robot move

Tags: animation

[image]I have a problem with the animation of a 4-legged spider robot (picture 1). I'm new to animation in Blender. The first time I managed to animate everything but the movements are too horrible for a robot (picture 2). The second time I managed the movements perfectly but I used a bone for each important part but I can't make it move because I can't use Inverse Kinematics because everything is destroyed, and the main body doesn't move (picture 3).
Can anyone help me arrange the bones and do the animation properly? Please.

Comment: Hi. You haven't actually added any pictures, these are just links to files on your computer. Please look at this guide on how to upload a pictures: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: Add picture #2 and 3.